# The difference between "object" and "object*"

Tags: c++

graph.h

```
struct Edge {
    int from;
    int to;
    int elabel;
    unsigned int id;
    Edge(): from(0), to(0), elabel(0), id(0) {};
};
```

What is the difference between `vector<Edge>`  and `vector<Edge*>`? I know `vector<Edge>` is an array storing `Edge` objects, but what is the `Edge*` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Edge*` type is a pointer-to-edge. So a `vector<Edge*>` is a vector that stores pointers-to-edges.

The vector itself doesn't store the objects, only pointers to those objects. This means in particular that the pointed-to objects don't get automatically deleted when the pointer's lifetime ends.

Comment: So it mean we generate the Edge object in other place, and we store the pointer which point to this object?

Comment: Yes, and you have to be very careful about the lifetime of those objects.

Answer (score 1):

`Edge*` is a pointer to an `Edge`. [Read up on Pointers in C++.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)